# Rem media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, pixel

I was wondering if it is a good practice to set the font size root element property to 62.5% in order to make easier the development of a responsive layout through media queries using REM and resolve the pixel problem limitations.
Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm afraid this is off topic, as it asks for opinions. Rather than one singular correct answer, you'll get people yelling at each other, dinnerware flying through the room etc. But if you really want an opinion, mine is here: [html {font-size:62.5%} is a mistake](https://mrlistersir.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/html-font-size62-5-is-a-mistake/).

Comment: Anyway, you can do media queries with rem even without changing to 62.5% first.